# How to change what program Calenders are opened in

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, default-programs, calendar, lightning

I was wondering... I have the Lightning plugin installed on Thunderbird, and I was wondering if I could have Calenders automatically opened in Thunderbird/lightning, instead of Gedit?

The only reason I'm asking, is because in the "Change Program" area, it only shows Gedit as an option. ([Click Here to see image. I can't post images until I have 10 rep](http://prntscr.com/cisxb))

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is Thunderbird fault here. You may want to subscribe and vote for this bug report which ask for a better handling of ics file: [Bug 357480 - Opening or adding .ics files to calendar by double click](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=357480)